# Creating a HTTP function without a name prefix

Tags: azure, kotlin, azure-functions

I would like to setup the following endpoints:

```
POST    /network-map/publish    
POST    /network-map/ack-parameters     
GET     /network-map    
GET     /network-map/node-info/{hash}   
GET     /network-map/network-parameters/{hash}
```

I am having issues creating the /network-map as I can't figure out how to create an endpoint without a prefix or suffix. I'm configuring this via the annotations below

```
@FunctionName("/network-map/hello")
fun hello(@HttpTrigger(name = "", methods = ["get"], authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
          @BindingName("name") name: String?,
          @BindingName("item") item: String?,
          context: ExecutionContext): String {
    return "Hello $name"
}

@FunctionName("/network-map/publish")
fun postNodeInfo(@HttpTrigger(name = "", methods = ["post"], authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS, dataType = "binary")
                 input: ByteArray): String {
    val deSerializedNode = input.deserialize<SignedNodeInfo>()
    deSerializedNode.verified()
    deSerializedNode.raw.hash
    return "ok";
}

@FunctionName("/network-map")
fun getNetworkMap(@HttpTrigger(name = "", methods = ["get"], authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) token: String?): ByteArray {
    return ByteArray(0)
}
```

It builds happily, but on run:

```
[15/03/2018 16:46:20] Job host started
[15/03/2018 16:46:20] The following 1 functions are in error:
[15/03/2018 16:46:20] network-map: The binding name  is invalid. Please assign a valid name to the binding.
[15/03/2018 16:46:20]
```

I'm happy to use the JSON configuration directly to achieve this, but I just can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The FunctionName attribute is used for applying a human readable label to your function, it shouldn't be used for attaching routing information. It's used as a fallback value when you don't explicitly provide routing information.

You can specify the routing information in the `@HttpTrigger` annotation by including an additional parameter: `route = "network-map/publish"`.